# How does this example receive information from YouTube?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS/HTML. I am fluent in Java, C++, C, and ok in Assembly. I am trying to encode this in my website:

http://jsfiddle.net/NmvA9/7743/

```
<html>
```

I understand for the most part what is going on (colors, sizes, basic code flow, etc.)

What I cant figure out is how to get it to display 'my' playlist instead of the example playlist. I don't see where the code points to a channel/playlist.

I don't see any playlist id or video ids in the code.

Where does this example point to YouTube?

Comment: It's probably the `allopts.user` in the sample code. Have you looked at the [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#player').youTubeChannel({
    user: 'putyouryoutubeusernamehere'
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I knew I was missing something. Is there an easy way to point it to a playlist within a channel?

Comment: You know youtube lets you embed a playlist without using scripts? https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: Ya I know. I just don't like the look of the new interface.  I like the tiles on the side.